# use gtk in a nautilus extension using python

Tags: python, gtk, nautilus

The following code

```
import gtk
import nautilus
import os
def alert(message):
    """A function to debug"""
    dialog = gtk.MessageDialog(None, gtk.DIALOG_MODAL, gtk.MESSAGE_INFO, gtk.BUTTONS_CLOSE, message)
    dialog.run()
    dialog.destroy()

class TestExtension(nautilus.MenuProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_file_items(self, window, files):
        items = []
        """Called when the user selects a file in Nautilus."""
        item = nautilus.MenuItem("NautilusPython::test_item", "Test", "Test")
        item.connect("activate", self.menu_activate_cb, files)
        items.append(item)
        return items

    def menu_activate_cb(self, menu, files):
        """Called when the user selects the menu."""
        for name in files:
            alert(name)
```

does not produce any Messages.
However

```
import easygui
import nautilus
import os

def alert(message):
    """A function to debug"""
    easygui.msgbox(message)

class TestExtension(nautilus.MenuProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_file_items(self, window, files):
        items = []
        """Called when the user selects a file in Nautilus."""
        item = nautilus.MenuItem("NautilusPython::test_item", "Test", "Test")
        item.connect("activate", self.menu_activate_cb, files)
        items.append(item)
        return items

    def menu_activate_cb(self, menu, files):
        """Called when the user selects the menu."""
        for name in files:
            alert(name)
```

works nicely and produces the requested Messages.

Can someone explain this - or better - provide a workaround?

(Even better is that when moving the alert()-call into `get_file_items()` the message appears correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [nautilus mailing list](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/nautilus-list/2010-August/msg00020.html) Ahmad Sherif found my error:

> gtk.MessageDialog is not working with your code because the fifth argument
>   has to be either string or None, and the variable name is of type
>   nautilus.FileInfo, which means you need to call `alert(name.get_name())`
>   not just `alert(name)`
>   Please refer to [the docs](http://projects.gnome.org/nautilus-python/documentation/html/class-nautilus-python-file-info.html) for more info about nautilus.FileInfo.

Thanks to Ahmad for pointing this out.

In a [second posting](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/nautilus-list/2010-August/msg00022.html) Ahmad explained how to debug better:

> I think you could've obtained such debug info if you launched Nautilus 
>   from terminal. […]
>   You should quit Nautilus first (`nautilus -q`) then launch it (`nautilus --no-desktop`).
>   If [nautilus] did [automatically] re-spawn [after quitting], you should edit
>   /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop as follows (A backup of it would 
>   be a good idea):
>
> - Replace "X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true" with "X-GNOME-AutoRestart=false"
> - Comment this line out "X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Desktop" by "#" at the beginning of the line. Actually I forgot why I did this but this how my is my configuration :).
> - Add this line "AutostartCondition=GNOME /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop"
> - Finally, you should restart your session, then try quitting and launching again.
>
> Credits go to [wrc1944](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=69282) […] for the respawning solution.

Applying the steps Ahmad explained I was able to see the error-message my faulty code generated.